# Verification Gatling is sending events on Certain port

Tags: networking, gatling, scala-gatling, flux-influxdb

I am sending events through gatling using graphite protocol on default port 2003.All the set up is on local ( including influxdb and grafana as well).Now I want to verify in gatling logs that in actual events are passing through port 2003 .How to verify that ? In gatling debug logs I am not finding anything related with graphite or port 2003.

Please help. Also let me know if you want me to add more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to continue in the previous question... But let's continue then here. To understand what data sends Gatling, you can use the utility `netcat / nc`.

---

It will listen incoming on port 2003:

```
nc -k -l 2003
```

(don't forget to turn off Influx or pass another port in `nc` and Gatling's conf)

---

Also you can emulate Gatling's data without run and send directly to Influx:

```
echo "gatling.example.get_request.all.percentiles99 155 1615558965" | nc localhost 2003
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am able to push data in influxdb using Jmeter so it clearly means there is issue in my gatling setup .Also you were right that I need to create influx database first.Now I need to understand what special I need to do in my setup because as per documentation not much needed to be done from gatling side.

Comment: I switched off influx and set port 2010 in gatling's conf .After that I started test and saw nc -k -l 2010.No data reflected in the command .

Comment: Then you need to make sure that the required config is loaded. Perhaps issue in path or something like that... According to the documentation `gatling.conf` must be in `src/test/resources`.
Try to create new configuration file and pass his name `-Dgatling.conf.file=gatling-special.conf`


Documentation link - https://gatling.io/docs/gatling/reference/current/core/configuration/

Comment: if possible I can give +10 to you.Thanks a lot it worked

Comment: Always a pleasure!